# Is Saitama the fastest character in One Punch Man?

Tags: one-punch-man

In Season 2 episode 2 Saitama showed to Speed of Sound Sonic he was much faster than him. Speed of Sound Sonic is supposed to be a fast character, faster than Genos with its last upgrade. In the show is clearly shown that Saitama is the strongest character, but how about his speed? Is he also the fastest character in One Punch Man or are there characters which are equally or faster than him?

Comment: Considering he jumped from the moon to earth in 19.5 seconds. I would assume he is the fastest existence in the universe known to us at this point in time.

Comment: @Dimitrimx was that written or said in some official source or was it calculated? BTW, 19.5 seconds from the Moon to Earth is around 20500 km/s. Fastest known speed of an inanimated entity in the known real universe is around 300000 km/s . May be there is room for someone faster than him?

Comment: There's some youtube video about it saw a while back. But definitly calculated [here is a non-video calculation](https://blasterbrewmaster.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/nerdyness-level-maximum-saitamas-one-punch-man-power-estimated/) which roughly aligns with what you said as well ;)

Comment: He's clearly the fastest character on the show, however, there is the episode where Bang plays rock paper scissors with him and Saitama's reaction time was shown to be significantly inferior to that of Bang's considering the fact that Bang managed to hit him in every single round. Saitama also acknowledges Bang's speed in the episode. That said, Bang definitely cannot jump back to the earth from the moon in under 20s.

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 Maybe that episode was just made for fun, I mean it's not some serious situation right? He use his strength depends on the situation.

Comment: @kit Well, most of Saitama's fights aren't really serious situations. Plus, he was very irate about the whole thing and very determined to win considering how he almost killed Bang in the end. He seemed a lot more serious in comparison to say his fight with Boros.

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 He also has trouble smacking that mosquito, and can't keep up with King's gameplaying speed, and is the slowest at getting meat in a communal hot pot dinner, etc. There are several "gag" scenes of this nature that probably exist mostly just to be silly and bond characters, but also serve to underscore the idea that he has pretty fine control over his power and only utilizes an approximately normal human amount in more mundane situations.

Answer (score 6):

Without specific spoilers, the short way to put this is that Saitama has proven himself effortlessly faster and stronger than everyone he encounters, including those specifically known for being faster or stronger than everyone else (except Saitama; and Blast has not been seen in real action, and certainly not relative to Saitama).

Spoilers of certain specific events from the webcomic:

> Late in the Monster Association/Garou saga he encounters Flashy Flash in some tunnels.  Flash attacks him at high speed, assuming Saitama is a monster to dispatch.  Saitama effortlessly dodges.  Flash is shocked, and decides to try it again and makes another high speed (sneak) attack.  Saitama simply stops the blade between his fingers.

> Flashy Flash then later fights against Garou.  Garou proves himself faster than he can handle.  Saitama effortlessly keeps up with Garou's pace when they start fighting, however. Just when Garou thinks he's snuck into a blind spot, suddenly Saitama's eyes will shift to look directly at him, and Garou will back off, frustrated that he can't exploit any of the many openings Saitama has because he's simply not strong or fast enough to do so. I believe Garou has been stated by ONE to be comparable to Boros in overall power, though Garou fights primarily with skill and speed while Boros fought with sheer power.  Saitama could effortlessly handle both of them.

As I've mentioned in another Q&A:

> Saitama appears to be without limits. Dr. Genus talks about how every being in existence has an innate limiter on their power and growth, because beyond that they'd physically or mentally collapse.  With science, training, monsterification, etc. at most you can increase what your limit is.  But you'll still have one.  Saitama, on the other hand, removed his limiter entirely.  If he's correct, then Saitama is arbitrarily strong and arbitrarily fast. He just needs a reason to actually use more strength or speed.

Answer (score 1):

According to this astrophysicist, to destroy a meteor like Saitama did (yes, he explicity mentions Saitama and the meteor Saitama destroy) you would need to travel to 99.99999997% the speed of light. So Saitama moves as fast as the speed of light, and no one can be faster than him in One Punch Man since the speed of light is the fastest known speed in the universe.

[The Physics Of Stopping A Meteor With One Punch](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2016/07/27/the-physics-of-stopping-a-meteor-with-one-punch/#21cc17664b72)